# Translating an app's open graph object

Tags: facebook, localization, translation, facebook-opengraph, translate

I'm trying to translate some open graph objects I just got accepted, the object phrases got custom edit. But when I tried to edit them they show the default phrases, not the custom phrases. I translated the default phrases on this site: https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/browse.php?app=app_id but when I post a story, the story doesn't look translated. Is it because I'm translating the default phrases? I cannot find the custom ones.

Comment: I also had a problem with og translation - please subscribe to this bug and add your repro in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/440878672656079